# OpenXML multiline string replace (regex) showing as one long line

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a docx document with "@Address" in it- which I can replace with this:

```
public static void SearchAndReplace(string document)
{
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
{
    string docText = null;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
    {
        docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    Regex regexText = new Regex("@Address");
    docText = regexText.Replace(docText, multiLineString);

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
    {
        sw.Write(docText);
    }
}
}
```

Available here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb508261.aspx

the issue is the string is returned in a single line.

Am I doing something wrong or is there an alternative method I can use to replace my text with multiline text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to replace the newline characters with Break (`<w:br/>`) Wordprocessing element:

```
public static void SearchAndReplace(string document)
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
    {
        string docText = null;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
            docText = sr.ReadToEnd();

        Regex regexText = new Regex("@Address");

        string multiLineString = "Sample text.\nSample text.";
        multiLineString = multiLineString.Replace("\r\n", "\n")
                                         .Replace("\n", "<w:br/>");

        docText = regexText.Replace(docText, multiLineString);

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
            sw.Write(docText);
    }
}
```

Also, note that there are some other special characters as well, that need to be replaced to corresponding Wordprocessing element.
For example, `<w:tab/>`, `<w:noBreakHyphen/>`, `<w:softHyphen/>` and `<w:sym w:font="X" w:char="Y"/>`.

Comment: Thank you kindly this helps me immensely